# Enterprise Library Cache Manager "Index was outside the bounds of the array" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, enterprise-library

I have an intermittent issue with caching using the Microsoft Enterprise Library’s caching block in that when retrieving items from the cache I am getting an `Index was outside the bounds of the array` exception.  This is only happening intermittently on our production server and what I think is happening is that by the time the `cacheManager.Keys.CopyTo(currentCacheKeys, 0);` line executes the cache manager keys have been update by another process and the `currentCacheKeys` array defined in line above is no longer large enough to accommodate the new entries, hence the `Index was outside the bounds of the array` exception.

Is this a reasonable assumption and does anyone have any suggestions on an approach to circumvent this problem?    The only thing I can think of is using an [object lock type of approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) but I’m not sure if that will work because what would I need to lock?

```
public static string[] GetCacheKeys(int? instanceId)
{
    string[] cacheKeys = null;

    ICacheManager cacheManager = CacheFactory.GetCacheManager();
    if (cacheManager != null)
    {
        int cachedItemCount = cacheManager.Count;
        if (cachedItemCount > 0)
        {
            object[] currentCacheKeys = new object[cachedItemCount];
            cacheManager.Keys.CopyTo(currentCacheKeys, 0);

            if (currentCacheKeys != null && currentCacheKeys.Length > 0)
            {
                ArrayList cacheKeyList = new ArrayList();

                // omitted for brevity

                cacheKeys = (string[])cacheKeyList.ToArray(typeof(string));
            }
        }
    }

    return cacheKeys;
}
```

**Stack Trace**

```
Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

   at System.Array.InternalGetReference(Void* elemRef, Int32 rank, Int32* pIndices)
   at System.Collections.Hashtable.CopyKeys(Array array, Int32 arrayIndex)
   at ProjectName.Library.Helpers.CacheHelper.GetCacheKeys(Nullable`1 instanceId)
   ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused from a custom implementation of Enterprise Library when returning the CacheManager keys - what was happening was the array to store the keys was being defined, but by the time the keys were copied over the array wasn't big enough because newer keys had been added into the cache.  It was resolved by using the `CurrrentCacheState` property of the cache object passed into the CacheManager constructor, as opposed to `realCache.Keys`

```
    public ICollection Keys
    {
        get { return realCache.CurrentCacheState.Keys; }
    }
```

See full description [here](https://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/548801#post1256906)